# Create a simple python object and send it back to Mako.template.render()

Tags: python, mako

I am using Mako to create some configuration templates for network routers.

I would like to create a simple router Object i.e

**File routers.py**

```
class myRouter(Object):

     def name(self):
          return "Foo"

     def interfaces(self):
          return [{'name':'loopback','address':'127.0.0.1'},{...}]
```

and then render it using Mako and my template

**Exec:**

```
from mako import *
from routers import myRouter
z = myRouter()
mytemplate = Template(filename='config.mako')
print mytemplate.render(router=z)
```

**File config.mako**

```
Router name is ${router.name()}!
Router interfaces are :
% for i in router.interfaces():
     ${i.name} -> ${i.address}
% endfor
```

**Output:**

> Router name is

```
<bound method Router.name of <pyrouteur.Router object
> at 0x7fa10a912310>>
```

> 

How can I avoid this behavior?

Thks!

Comment: It works for me.  The only thing I changed is the base clase of `myRouter`: I used `object` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the class `myRouter` and then pass that to the render method, currently you are passing the class itself as the argument.

Your code should look something like this:

```
r = myRouter()
t.render(router =r)
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but I got the same output with a different hex address though